# Unable to load Tor website. Copy Tor log to clipboard

Tags: help, time, connection

when i am trying to connect to Tor browsers. It get stuck in the middle. And in the bottom title "Copy Tor log to Clipboard" comes out. Please Help me out with that. I have pressed copy Tor log to clipboard and this is what comes:

```
07/03/2017, 16:54:43.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
07/03/2017, 16:54:43.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
07/03/2017, 16:54:43.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
07/03/2017, 16:54:43.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
07/03/2017, 16:54:43.200 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "/Users/user/Desktop/TorBrowser-Data/Tor/torrc.orig.1" 
07/03/2017, 16:54:44.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
07/03/2017, 16:54:44.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
07/03/2017, 16:54:44.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
07/03/2017, 16:54:44.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
07/03/2017, 16:54:44.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
07/03/2017, 16:54:44.700 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
07/03/2017, 16:54:44.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 40%: Loading authority key certs 
07/03/2017, 16:54:44.900 [WARN] Our clock is 5 minutes, 16 seconds behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2017-03-07 16:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings! 
07/03/2017, 16:54:44.900 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
07/03/2017, 16:57:18.200 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
07/03/2017, 16:57:18.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
07/03/2017, 16:57:18.200 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
07/03/2017, 16:57:18.900 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your logs:

```
07/03/2017, 16:54:44.900 [WARN] Our clock is 5 minutes, 16 seconds behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2017-03-07 16:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings!
```

You need to synchronize your time using NTP or a local GPS receiver: big time drift is a blocker to enter a Tor network, and for a good reason - cryptography and signature verification is relying on precise *and* synchronized time on *both* sides. But be warned: sometimes an attackers(including ISP's and censorship guys) are using NTP to de-synchronize your local time and put you out of the network. So if you need a stronger protection - use a GPS module *with* PPS signal, it will make your clock precisely set by a satellite signals.